# OSX Displaying default window after event

Tags: macos

I have managed to produce some nice iPhone apps, however I have now been asked to try my hand at an OSX app. The change in a major, however I have a specific problem.

I am writing an application that watches for a specific manufacturer and device ID on USB. Until it finds it, I only want the menu to show, not window. I have this. I also have the code in place to detect the USB device, so when I detect it, the first thing I want to do is display my main window. The following code is in my main.m file just after device detection.

```
    NSWindowController *mainWindow=[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainMenu"];
    [mainWindow showWindow:self];
```

From everything I have read, this should work, however... "self" is an undeclared identifier. I know this will be something simple, however I can't for the life of my think what! :-)
Thanks in advance
Chris H

Comment: I don't know why you would get that error.  You can pass nil there, have you tried that?

Comment: tried nil and the app crashed 2012-08-17 17:52:26.591 Changers[10814:8c03] Could not connect the action orderFrontStandardAboutPanel: to target of class NSWindowController

Comment: I think that has something to do with what's the file's owner.  FWIW, I never liked or saw the use for NSWindow controller.  If I want 2 windows in an app, I just create them both in the same xib file and uncheck the "Visible At Launch" box for the one you want to show later. Then just show it with [newWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self].